# Can I use "Stop" as subroutine name in VB?

Tags: vb6

I'd like to create an object... say a "Movie" object. The object should have a method name "Stop", so I can have this code below

```
dim Mov as new Movie
Mov.Stop ' To execute the Stop method.
```

In my Movie class, I should have something like this.

```
Sub Stop()
'code here needed for the Stop subroutine
End Sub
```

However, I can't use "Stop" as name as this is a reserved word. I see a VB code that has "Stop" as one of the method. Unfortunately, the code is protected so I can't view it.

How can I name a subroutine as "Stop"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might work if you created a typelib with Stop and your other methods and properties and then use Implements in your class.  I haven't tested this though.

Update:

See [Tutorial: Using Reserved Words as VB6 Class Member Names](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?711589-Tutorial-Using-Reserved-Words-as-VB6-Class-Member-Names&p=4353295#post4353295)

Comment: Thanks for verifying this.  I can use it myself, often wanting a Close method or such.  Hmm, I suppose it doesn't even have to be complete, just cover the members with the reserved word collisions you may have.

Answer (score 2):

`Stop` is a statement used to break the app when debugging (same as setting a breakpoint) so choose another name.

Comment: As I said, I saw a VB code that has a "Stop" method in it. There should be a way to define it.

Comment: VB could call a method called .Stop from a library written in something other than VB where Stop is not reserved (or one written in VB with a custom typelib perhaps) but you can't create a method in VB6 called `Stop` any more than you could create a `Sub Dim()`.

Comment: +1 You can work round some of the naming restrictions in VB6 by enclosing identifiers in brackets ([ ]). But not this one - choose another name.

Answer (score 0):

Stop is a keyword in Vb6.
You will have to rename your method to something different.
Say `MovieStop`

Comment: just my 2 cents StopMovie will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub [Stop]()
   ' code
end sub
```

Comment: please explain why this is a viable solution to the question, code only answers are discouraged on SO.